# Python - How to get all keys where values are zero from list of dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x

I have list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
    planets = [
  { "name": "Mercury", "moonCount": 0 },
  { "name": "Venus", "moonCount": 0 },
  { "name": "Earth", "moonCount": 1 },
  {
    "name": "Mars",
    "moonCount": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Jupiter",
    "moonCount": 67
  },
  {
    "name": "Saturn",
    "moonCount": 62
  },
  {
    "name": "Uranus",
    "moonCount": 27
  },
  {
    "name": "Neptune",
    "moonCount": 13
  },
  {
    "name": "Pluto",
    "moonCount": 4
  }
]
```

I am trying to get the list of all planets which do not have moons.
I can do this very simply if turn this into panda dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(planets)
no_moon_planets = df.loc[df['moonCount']==0, 'name']
no_moon_planets = no_moon_planets.tolist()
no_moon_planets
```

But I need to do this without creating panda dataframe. So basically looking for solution where I can extract the list of the planet directly from list of dictionaries where the number of the moons iz zero.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following :

```
Planets_without_moon = [i['name'] for i in planets if i['moonCount']==0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with list comprehension:

```
zero_moon = [dic for dic in planets if dic["moonCount"]==0]
```

if you just want the name of the planet:

```
zero_moon = [dic["name"] for dic in planets if dic["moonCount"]==0]
```